# Infinite retry in spring kafka consumer @retryabletopic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I am using @RetryableTopic to implement retry logic in kafka consumer.
I gave config as below:

```
@RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "4",
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 300000, multiplier = 10.0),
            autoCreateTopics = "false",
            topicSuffixingStrategy = SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE
    )
```

However, instead of retrying for 4 times, it retries infinitely, and that too in no delay time. Can someone please help me with the code?
I want the message to be retried 4 times with first time delay- after 5 mins, then 2nd delay after 10 mins, third delay after 20 mins...

Code is below:

```
int i = 1;

@RetryableTopic(
        attempts = "4",
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 300000, multiplier = 10.0),
        autoCreateTopics = "false",
        topicSuffixingStrategy = SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE
)
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic_string_data", containerFactory = "default")
public void consume(@Payload String message , @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    String prachi = null;
    System.out.println("current time: " + new Date());
    System.out.println("retry method invoked -> " + i++ + " times from topic: " + topic);
    System.out.println("current time: " + new Date());
    prachi.equals("abc");
}

@DltHandler
public void listenDlt(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                      @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset) {
    System.out.println("current time dlt: " + new Date());
    System.out.println("DLT Received: " + in + " from " + topic + " offset " + offset + " -> " + i++ + " times");
    System.out.println("current time dlt: " + new Date());
    //dump event to dlt queue
}
```

Kafka config:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grp_STRING");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);

    //inject consumer factory to kafka listener consumer factory
}

@Bean(name = "default")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

Logs when running app: this is not the complete logs:

```
32:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.186  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.187  INFO 96675 --- [ner#6-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-7, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-dlt-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.187  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions assigned: [topic_string_data-retry-0-0]
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.187  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-2, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=27, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.187  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions assigned: [topic_string_data-retry-1-0]
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.187  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.188  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-2, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=24, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.188  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-4, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.188  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-4, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.188  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions assigned: [topic_string_data-retry-2-0]
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.188  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions assigned: [topic_string_data-1, topic_string_data-0]
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.189  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions assigned: [topic_string-1, topic_string-0]
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.188  INFO 96675 --- [ner#6-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-7, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-dlt-2 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.190  INFO 96675 --- [ner#6-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-7, groupId=grp_STRING] Setting offset for partition topic_string_data-dlt-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=14, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[197mumnb29632:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.191  INFO 96675 --- [ner#6-dlt-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions assigned: [topic_string_data-dlt-0, topic_string_data-dlt-1, topic_string_data-dlt-2]
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.196  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 1 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.196  WARN 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaBackoffException: Partition 0 from topic topic_string_data-retry-1 is not ready for consumption, backing off for approx. 26346 millis.
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:40 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 3 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:40 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:40.713  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 2 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:40 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 4 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:40 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:41.228  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 3 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:41 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 5 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:41 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:41.740  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 4 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:41 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 6 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:41 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:42.254  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 5 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:42 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 7 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:42 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:42.777  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 6 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:42 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 8 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:42 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:43.298  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 7 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:43 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 9 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:43 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:58:43.809  INFO 96675 --- [3-retry-0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-3, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 8 for partition topic_string_data-retry-0-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:43 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 10 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:58:43 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:10 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 11 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:10 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:10.733  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 2 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    2022-02-23 13:59:10.736  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 1 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    2022-02-23 13:59:10.737  WARN 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaBackoffException: Partition 0 from topic topic_string_data-retry-2 is not ready for consumption, backing off for approx. 29483 millis.
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:10 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 12 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:10 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:11.249  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 3 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:11 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 13 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:11 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:11.769  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 4 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:11 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 14 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:11 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:12.286  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 5 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:12 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 15 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:12 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:12.805  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 6 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:12 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 16 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:12 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:13.339  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 7 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:13 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 17 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:13 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:13.856  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 8 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:13 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 18 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:13 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:14.372  INFO 96675 --- [4-retry-1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-6, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 9 for partition topic_string_data-retry-1-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:14 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 19 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-1
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:14 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:40 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 20 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:40 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:40.846  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 2 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:40 IST 2022
    DLT Received: prachi from topic_string_data-dlt offset 14 -> 21 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:46 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:46 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 22 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:46 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:47.466  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 3 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    DLT Received: prachi from topic_string_data-dlt offset 15 -> 23 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 24 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:47.981  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 4 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    DLT Received: prachisharma from topic_string_data-dlt offset 16 -> 25 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 26 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:47 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:48.493  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 5 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:48 IST 2022
    DLT Received: hie from topic_string_data-dlt offset 17 -> 27 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:48 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:48 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 28 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:48 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:49.011  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 6 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    DLT Received: hieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee from topic_string_data-dlt offset 18 -> 29 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 30 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:49.527  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 7 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    DLT Received: hie from topic_string_data-dlt offset 19 -> 31 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 32 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:49 IST 2022
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    DLT Received: hi from topic_string_data-dlt offset 20 -> 33 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:50.039  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 8 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 34 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    2022-02-23 13:59:50.545  INFO 96675 --- [5-retry-2-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-1, groupId=grp_STRING] Seeking to offset 9 for partition topic_string_data-retry-2-0
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    DLT Received: hi from topic_string_data-dlt offset 21 -> 35 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    retry method invoked -> 36 times from topic: topic_string_data-retry-2
    current time: Wed Feb 23 13:59:50 IST 2022
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:51 IST 2022
    DLT Received: hi from topic_string_data-dlt offset 22 -> 37 times
    current time dlt: Wed Feb 23 13:59:51 IST 2022
```

Comment: I've run your code and it works as expected. Can you share the spring-boot and spring-kaka version you're using, and also the logic you use to send the messages? Seems like you're either sending the message too many times, or you already have that many messages in your topic and is reading from the beginning.

Comment: @TomazFernandes If you see the logs, the count is incremented to 35 at DLT. I am using CLI to send messages. Spring Kafka version - 2.7.9. Apache kafka version 3.0. And springboot version - 2.6.3
I believe that it read all the messages i sent in the topic (offset=earliest)

Comment: @TomazFernandes - I am not able to achieve this condition :
 message to be retried 4 times with first time delay- after 10 mins, then 2nd delay after 30 mins, third delay after 90 mins...
Can you help me with the backoff condition?

Comment: Hi @PrachiSharma we are not using retriable topics at all, but I want to achieve same behaviour. Can you help here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there are two separate problems.

One is that you seem to already have records in the topics, and if you have it configured to `earliest` the app will read all those records  when it starts up. You can either set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `latest`, or, if you're running locally on docker, you can stop the Kafka container and prune the volumes with something like `docker system prune --volumes` (note that this will erase data from all your stopped containers - use wisely).

Can you try one of these and test again?

<s>The other problem is that the framework is wrongly setting the default maxDelay of 30s even though the annotation states the default is to ignore. I'll open an issue for that and add the link here.</s>

<s>For now</s> You can set a maxDelay such as `@Backoff(delay = 600000, multiplier = 3.0, maxDelay = 5400000)`, then the application should have the correct delays for 10, 30 and 90 minutes as you wanted.

Let me know if that works out for you, or if you have any other problems related to this issue.

EDIT: Issue opened, you can follow the development there https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2137

<s>It should be fixed in the next release.</s>

EDIT 2: Actually the phrasing in the `@BackOff` annotation is rather ambiguous, but seems like the behavior is correct and you should explicitly set a larger maxDelay.

The documentation should clarify this behavior in the next release.

EDIT 3: To answer your question in the comments, the way retryable topics work is the partition is paused for the duration of the delay, but the consumer keeps polling the broker, so longer delays don't trigger rebalancing.

From your logs the rebalancing is from the main topic's partitions, so it's unlikely it has anything to do with this feature.

EDIT 4: The Retryable Topics feature was released in Spring for Apache Kafka 2.7.0, which uses kafka-clients 2.7.0. However, there have been several improvements to the feature, so I recommend using the latest Spring Kafka version (currently 2.8.3) if possible to benefit from those.

Comment: Explicitly giving maxDelay on backoff strategy works as I expected. Thanks Tomaz :)

Comment: Just one more question, If i want a delay time of 6 hours, which is greater than the max.poll.interval.ms, then what will be the behaviour? Will there be a partition re-balancing? As you can see that i have not given any explicit value for max.poll.interval.ms in my config. What will be default behaviour of my consumer?

Comment: I saw in my logs: 2022-02-23 13:58:39.683  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-2, groupId=grp_STRING] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2022-02-23 13:58:39.684  INFO 96675 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-grp_STRING-2, groupId=grp_STRING] Revoke previously assigned partitions topic_string_data-1, topic_string_data-0
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : grp_STRING: partitions revoked: [topic_string_data-1, topic_string_data-0]

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) I've further edited the answer to address this question about rebalancing. If the answer as a whole addresses your original question, please mark the answer as accepted so other users can easily spot it. Thanks

Comment: Also, is this retry functionality compatible with 2.13-2.8.0 Apache kafka version?
Starting from which kafka version is this supported?

Comment: I've edited the answer with this response. Since the original question has been addressed, feel free to open a new question if there's anything else - it gets hard for other people to find questions in the comments. And thanks for providing feedback on the feature.